# Remove line breaks/spaces from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, line-breaks

I am having trouble removing line breaks from my text in javascript.  Here is an example of the data I am working with:

```
0: "Christian Pulisic"
1: "↵"
2: "From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"
3: "↵" 
4: "Christian Pulisic"
5: "↵"
6: "Personal information"
7: "↵"
8: "Full name   Christian Mate Pulisic[1]"
```

Obviously, the line spaces/breaks or whatever you call them, are polluting the data I am getting.

I cannot get the following function to recognize the line breaks and replace it with a "" which I then can very easily remove from the array through another function I run my data through.

This is the code I am currently using that is not working:

```
for (i in cleanArray){
    cleanArray[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
};

console.log(cleanArray);
```

Comment: The replace() method returns a new string, it doesn't change the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cleanArray[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")` will return a new string. Furthermore, strings are immutable in JavaScript. Change it to

```
for(var i = 0; i < cleanArray.length; ++i)
    cleanArray[i] = cleanArray[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
```

Comment: or a bit shorter: cleanArray.map(i => i.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the characters shown as `"↵"` are actual newlines**

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
var newArr = arr.filter(el => el.trim());
```

Comment: Tried this and it did not work:
 'var cleanerArray=[];
 for (i in cleanArray){
  cleanerArray.push(cleanArray[i].trim)
 };
 
 console.log(cleanerArray);'

Comment: `cleanerArray.push(cleanArray[i].trim)` note that the function `trim` is not called. Use `cleanerArray.push(cleanArray[i].trim())`

Comment: @Lance You need to call `trim()` ^^^^